# Fork() function in C programming

Tags: c, fork

I just need to understand this statement:

```
if (fork() && !fork())
```

shouldn't it always be false? I mean, if I write:

```
if (a && !a)
```

It's always false so the first should always be false too, am I wrong? Of course I am, but I'm hoping someone can explain this strange thing to me.

I'm studying C for an exam and I had to resolve this code:

```
int main(){
if(fork && !fork()){
   printf("a\n");
}
else printf("b\n");
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you edited your question and formatted what code you have into code segments

Comment: Only if `fork` returns the same value twice... (Some context would be nice, but note that the return value is different in the 2 processes created).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every calls to the unix process creation system call fork() returns twice. First it returns with the PID of the child to the parent(the process which called fork()). Second it returns to 0 to the newly created child.

from man pages:

**Return Value**

**On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child. On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.**

in your case

```
if (fork() && !fork())
```

The statement inside `if` , calls fork twice. So what will happen is following :

```
A
|----------------B
|                |
|---C            |
|   |            |
```

Now first call to `fork()` will return in both A and B. In A it will be nonzero and in B it will be zero.

Second call to fork() will be evoked only from A. because first fork returned 0 to B, it will not Evoke a second `fork()`. **its because `&&` short circuits the evaluation if first operand is found non zero.** Thanks to Daniel for pointing this out.

So we can make a table out of this:

```
PID       fork()1      fork()2
------------------------------
A           >0          >0
B           =0          >0
C           >0          =0
```

So from the chart, Process C's `if` will be evaluated to **TRUE**

Its important to remember, `fork()1` didn't returned to C . it got the copy of **Already evaluated expression** from its parent.

I hope this explains your question.

Comment: [I said it before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420932/fork-function-in-c-programming#comment15064848_11421071): There will be only three processes, the first child doesn't `fork()` since `&&` short-cuts.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I overlooked it. I'm editing my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Good. It's a nice explanation once you fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

First off, is a function. It may not always return the same value.

In this case specifically, fork is a function which creates another process. The original process gets a positive return value (of the child's pid) and the child process gets a return value of 0.

In your code, there end up being a total of three processes. The if statement will evaluate to true for 1 of them (process C below).

```
     A
     |__________B
     |          |
     |__C       |
     |  |       |       
     |  |       |
```

Comment: There will be only three processes, the first child doesn't `fork()` since `&&` short-cuts.

Comment: How can I know for which process the if statement will be true?@DanielFischer

Comment: In the diagram above, it would be process C. When a process forks, the child gets a return value of 0, while the parent gets a return value with the pid of the child. On the first fork, B is the child and gets a return value of 0, failing the test. A gets a non-zero return value and continues. It then forks again and again receives a non-zero return value. Since we are testing !fork() though, this now causes A to fail the test. C is created with a return value of 0, which tests true under negation, and therefore passes into the body of the if.

Answer (score 3):

```
shouldn't be always false?
```

No.

Because it's not a variable, each call to`fork()` creates a new child process.

Comment: So what does the statement if(fork() && !fork()) means?

Comment: Which returns 0 in the child and pid (not a 0) in its parent.

Comment: Do something in the second child of the parent. You really better post the whole code.

Comment: There are 2 possibilities. If each `fork()` returns a PID (child) then condition will be false. Or if at least one returns 0 then it'll be true. Can you post a little more code to understand the context better?

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `fork()` returns two values, one to each process. So for each decision, there's one process that takes each path.

Answer (score 0):

The `fork()` function call returns 0 to the child process and the process ID to the parent process. Basically, what this does is forks once. If the process is the parent, it jumps to next block, the child then forks again. The parent of this process jumps to the next block, and the child in this block executes the code in the `if` statement.