# Can anyone please explain me the execution of this program. how fork is working here

Tags: c, unix, fork

Can anyone please explain me the working of this program and also explain me the output its printing hello World 20 times.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main(){

  if(fork() && fork()){
    fork();
  }

  if(fork() || fork()){
    fork();
  }

  printf("Hello World");
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Draw a diagram on paper and you'll figure it out. Remember that the logical operators are short-circuited.

Comment: Here is a good explanation of how the logical operators are [short-circuited](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11421358/2705293)

Comment: Remember that each test of `fork()` is equivalent to `fork() != 0`, and also that `fork()` returns 0 in the child process but not in the parent (the parent either gets -1 on fork failure or the PID of the child, which is never 0).

Comment: It is curious to see `<conio.h>` in a question tagged Unix; it's a header that doesn't exist on Unix.  You should not need `<sys/types.h>` directly; you should have `<unistd.h>`. Handling `getch()` on Unix is an interesting proposition. For most practical purposes, on Unix you do not need (want) that at all.  It is a very Windows-ish construct.

Comment: Also, there are a couple of dupes and very similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

`fork()` returns:

- in parent: pid of the child
- in child: 0

So lets mark each fork as A, B, C, D, E, F, and each process P0, P1, etc:

```
int main(){

  if(A && B){
    C;
  }

  if(D || E){
    F;
  }

  printf("Hello World");
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Here are the processes generated at each fork:

```
P0:
  A -> P1
  B -> P2
  C -> P3
  D -> P4
  F -> P5

P1:
 D -> P6
 F -> P7

P2:
 D -> P8
 F -> P9

P3:
 D -> P10
 F -> P11

P4:
 E -> P12
 F -> P13

P5:
 -

P6:
 E -> P14
 F -> P15

P7:
 -

P8:
 E -> P16
 F -> P17

P9:
 -

P10:
 E -> P18
 F -> P19

P11 - P19:
 -
```

So you have 20 processes.

---

Lets discuss on 2 of these:

P1 is the process generated by fork A in P0.
So in P1, A returns 0, so B and C are not evaluated (in the first `if` the first operand of `&&` is `false` so the expression is short-circuited and the `if condition` is `false`).
D is evaluated and return !=0, so E is not evaluated, F is evaluated (in the second `if`, the first operand of `||` is true, so the expression is short-circuited and the `if condition` returns true).
So P1 generated new programs by forks D and F.

P8 is the process generated by fork D in P2. So D return 0. E is evaluated and return 1 and F is evaluated. So P8 generated new process by fork E and F.

Comment: I think I answered this more for my amusement to see if I get it right than to answer his question.